# Deducing Lambda Capture Types

Tags: c++, c++11

I've recently found that capturing a `const` object by value in a lambda, implies that the variable inside the labmda's body (i.e. the lambda's data member) is also `const`.
For example:

```
const int x = 0;
auto foo = [x]{
  // x is const int
};
```

This behavior is mentioned in § 8.1.5.2 in the [draft for C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf):

> For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type. The
>   declaration order of these members is unspecified. The type of such a data member is the referenced type
>   if the entity is a reference to an object, an lvalue reference to the referenced function type if the entity
>   is a reference to a function, **or the type of the corresponding captured entity otherwise**. A member of an
>   anonymous union shall not be captured by copy.

I would expect that deducing type of captured variables will be the same as deducing auto.
Is there a good reason for having different type-deduction rules for captured types?

Answer (score 8):

In your example, it would not be possible to modify `x` since the lambda is not `mutable`, which makes the function call operator `const`. But even if the lambda is `mutable`, it's true that the quoted passage makes the type of `x` in the lambda `const int`.

If I remember correctly, this was a deliberate design decision in C++11 to make the use of `x` within the lambda behave similarly to the use of `x` in the enclosing scope. That is,

```
void foo(int&);
void foo(const int&);
const int x = 0;
foo(x);  // calls foo(const int&)
auto foo = [x]() mutable {
    foo(x);  // also calls foo(const int&)
};
```

This helps to avoid bugs when, *e.g.,* some code is rewritten from having an explicit loop to calling a standard library algorithm with a lambda.

If I'm wrong about this recollection, hopefully someone with the right answer will step in and write their own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the reasoning; There is already a comprehensive answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56811738/2079303).

For those who want to know how to capture a non-const copy of a const variable, you can use a capture with an initialiser:

```
const int x = 0;
auto foo = [x = x]() mutable {
    // x is non-const
};
```

That requires C++14 though. A C++11 compatible solution is to make the copy outside the lambda:

```
const int x = 0;
int copy = x;
auto foo = [copy]() mutable {
    // copy is non-const
};
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but it would require the `C++14` tag

Comment: @LWimsey Oh; Good point considering the C++11 tag; I didn't notice it.

Comment: Did you mean `auto foo = [copy]...`?

Comment: @PaulSanders yes, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `operator()` in lambda is `const` by default.

```
int main()
{
    const int x = 0;
    auto foo = [x](){}; // main::$_0::operator()() const
    foo();
}
```

So you have to use `mutable` lambda:

```
int main()
{
    const int x = 0;
    auto foo = [x=x](){}; // main::$_0::operator()()
    foo();
}
```

Comment: `mutable` will make `operator()` non-const, but for the captured object (without initializer), the type is presserved, which includes `const` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a good reason for having different type-deduction rules for captured types?

This was deliberate decision (with rationale/reasons cited from CWG 756 below), and part of the rewrite of the original lambda proposal,

- [N2550: Lambda Expressions and Closures:
  Wording for Monomorphic Lambdas (Revision 4)](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2550.pdf)

by

- [N2927: New wording for C++0x Lambdas (rev. 2)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2927.pdf)

> During the meeting of March 2009 in Summit, a large number of issues relating to C++0x
> Lambdas were raised and reviewed by the core working group (CWG). After deciding on a clear
> direction for most of these issues, CWG concluded that it was preferable to rewrite the section
> on Lambdas to implement that direction. This paper presents this rewrite.

Particularly its resolution of CWG 756 [**emphasis** mine]:

- [CWG 756. Dropping cv-qualification on members of closure objects](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#756)

> [...] Consider the following example:
>
> ```
> void f() {
>   int const N = 10;
>   [=]() mutable { N = 30; }  // Okay: this->N has type int, not int const.
>   N = 20;  // Error.
> }
> ```
>
> That is, the N that is a member of the closure object is not const,
> even though the captured variable is const. This seems strange, **as
> capturing is basically a means of capturing the local environment** in a
> way that avoids lifetime issues. More seriously, **the change of type
> means that the results of decltype, overload resolution, and template
> argument deduction applied to a captured variable inside a lambda
> expression can be different from those in the scope containing the
> lambda expression**, which could be a subtle source of bugs.