# Why do fields in non-mutable lambdas use "const" when capturing const values or const references?

Tags: c++, lambda, constants, language-lawyer, mutable

As seen in the question [lambda capture by value mutable doesn't work with const &?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485041/lambda-capture-by-value-mutable-doesnt-work-with-const), when capturing a value of type `const T&` using its name or `[=]` in a mutable lambda, the field in the hidden class gets type `const T`. It could be argued for that this is the correct thing to do for mutable lambdas.

But why is this done for non-mutable lambdas too? In non-mutable lambdas, the `operator()(...)` is declared `const`, so it can't modify captured values anyway.

The bad consequences of this happen when we move the lambda, for example when wrapping it in an `std::function`.

See the following two examples:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

std::function<void()> f1, f2;

struct Test {
    Test() {puts("Construct");}
    Test(const Test& o) {puts("Copy");}
    Test(Test&& o) {puts("Move");}
    ~Test() {puts("Destruct");}
};

void set_f1(const Test& v) {
    f1 = [v] () {}; // field type in lambda object will be "const Test"
}

void set_f2(const Test& v) {
    f2 = [v = v] () {}; // field type in lambda object will be "Test"
}

int main() {
    Test t;
    puts("set_f1:");
    set_f1(t);
    puts("set_f2:");
    set_f2(t);
    puts("done");
}
```

We get the following compiler-generated lambda classes:

```
class set_f1_lambda {
    const Test v;
public:
    void operator()() const {}
};

class set_f2_lambda {
    Test v;
public:
    void operator()() const {}
};
```

The program prints the following (using gcc or clang):

```
Construct
set_f1:
Copy
Copy
Copy
Destruct
Destruct
set_f2:
Copy
Move
Move
Destruct
Destruct
done
Destruct
Destruct
Destruct
```

The `v` value is copied not less than three time in the first example `set_f1`.

In the second example `set_f2`, the only copy is when capturing the value (as expected). The fact that two moves are used is an implementation detail in libstdc++. The first move happens internally in `operator=` in `std::function` when passing the functor by value to an internal function (why doesn't this function signature use pass-by-reference?). The second move happens when move constructing the final heap-allocated functor.

The move constructor of the lambda functor object however, can't use a move constructor for a field if the field is `const` (since such a constructor can't "clear out" a const variable after stealing its content). That's why the copy constructor must be used instead for such fields.

So to me it seems to only have negative impact to capture values as `const` in non-mutable lambdas. Did I miss something important, or has it simply been standardised this way to make the standard more simpler somehow?

Comment: Similar question without a satisfying answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56811624/deducing-lambda-capture-types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Did I miss something important, or has it simply been standardised this way to make the standard more simpler somehow?

The original lambda proposal,

- [N2550: Lambda Expressions and Closures:
  Wording for Monomorphic Lambdas (Revision 4)](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2550.pdf)

differentiated between the captured object's type and the type of the corresponding data member of the lambda's closure type:

> /6 The type of the closure object is a class with a unique name, call it F, considered to be defined at the point where the
> lambda expression occurs.
>
> Each name N in the effective capture set is looked up in the context
> where the lambda expression appears **to determine its object type**;
> **in the case of a reference, the object type is the type to which the reference refers**. For each element in the effective capture set, F
> has a private non-static data member as follows:
>
> - if the element is this, the data member has some unique name, call it t, and is of the type of this ([class.this],
>   9.3.2);
> - if the element is of the form & N, the data member has the name N and type “reference to object type of N”;
>   5.19. CONSTANT EXPRESSIONS 3
> - **otherwise, the element is of the form N,** the data member has the name N and type “**cv-unqualified object type** of N”.

In this original wording OP's examples would not result in a `const`-qualified data member `v`. We may also note that we recognize the wording

> in the case of a reference, the object type is the type to which the reference refers

which is present (but directly stating *the type of the data member* as opposed to the object type) in [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#10.sentence-4) of the (most recent draft of) the eventual wording on lambdas:

> The type of such a data member **is the referenced type if the entity is a reference to an object**, an lvalue reference to the referenced function type if the entity is a reference to a function, or the type of the corresponding captured entity otherwise.

What happened was

- [N2927: New wording for C++0x Lambdas (rev. 2)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2927.pdf)

which re-wrote a large part of the wording from N2550:

> During the meeting of March 2009 in Summit, a large number of issues relating to C++0x
> Lambdas were raised and reviewed by the core working group (CWG). After deciding on a clear
> direction for most of these issues, CWG concluded that it was preferable to rewrite the section
> on Lambdas to implement that direction. This paper presents this rewrite.

particularly, for the context of this question, resolving CWG issue

- [CWG 756. Dropping cv-qualification on members of closure objects](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#756)

> [...] Consider the following example:
>
> ```
> void f() {
>   int const N = 10;
>   [=]() mutable { N = 30; }  // Okay: this->N has type int, not int const.
>   N = 20;  // Error.
> }
> ```
>
> That is, the N that is a member of the closure object is not const,
> even though the captured variable is const. **This seems strange, as
> capturing is basically a means of capturing the local environment in a
> way that avoids lifetime issues.** More seriously, the change of type
> means that the results of decltype, overload resolution, and template
> argument deduction applied to a captured variable inside a lambda
> expression can be different from those in the scope containing the
> lambda expression, which could be a subtle source of bugs.

after which the wording (as of N2927) was made into the one we saw eventually go into C++11

> The type of such a data member
> is the type of the corresponding captured entity if the entity is not a reference to an
> object, or the referenced type otherwise.

Were I dare to speculate, the resolution of CWG 756 also meant keeping cv-qualifiers for value-captures of entities that were of reference types, which may arguably have been an oversight.

Comment: I'm not sure if this really answers the question. This seems to be whether to make `mutable` default or not. What `mutable` currently does, is to remove the `const` keyword on `operator()(...)`, not the captured value types. Note that even in a mutable lambda, you cannot modify a captured-by-value parameter `const T&`. I updated my question to include the compiler-generated lambda classes.

Comment: @drfib To my reading, that paper uses that language of "captures implicitly const" loosely, either due to misunderstanding or just oversimplifying. The C++11 closure type in the examples it gives would not have const members, just a const call operator. And that const-ness could be avoided given the mutable keyword, which doesn't work in the OP. In other words, I agree that it doesn't quite answer the question as I would interpret it.

Comment: @JeffGarrett I just updated (/rewrote) the answer with some more historical points. Seems like the eventual wording, w.r.t. its effect on keeping cv-qualifiers for entities that are references to objects (when value-capturing), was an oversight.

Comment: Good digging. CWG 756 answers it for me. They wanted the use of the identifier inside the lambda to act the same as it would outside the lambda (template deduction, overload resolution, etc.) even if it were a copy. If that's the rationale, a by-value capture of ref-to-const being a const member is consistent with that. I don't agree with the decision, but it's good to know why it was made.

Comment: Yes that can make sense with a mutable lambda. But with a non-mutable lambda, overload resolution etc. will still use const since the `operator()()` is const, so there is no need to keep `const` for the functor fields in that case, right?

Comment: For a non-mutable lambda, there's fewer ways to observe the const vs. no-const, but it is observable. If you move-constructed another lambda from the source, the prior lambda would be left with the moved-from shells of members if they are non-const. The call operator would then observe those members as having changed, something that is not observable outside of the lambda. So, it seems consistent to me here too.

Comment: True, but using an object even after it has been moved is considered bad practice and the same applies in general if you attempt to use a "shell" of a moved object. Since using a moved object "should not be done" by proper programs, I don't see why this would be a good motivation for keeping const in non-mutable lambdas.

Comment: Ok I will accept this answer. I guess the decision was made for the mutable case in mind, and to keep the spec simple or just an oversight, don't make any difference for how variables are captured between mutable and non-mutable lambdas.